# Fragment instance is null

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to add a fragment via programming and then calling one of its method. I get null pointer exception while invoking any items of fragment.

```
    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_inner_container, fragment).commit();
((HomeFragment) fragment).homeSelected(true);
```

and then in Fragment

```
public void homeSelected(boolean val) {

        if (val) {
            homeButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.header_bg));
        } else {
            homeButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.screen_bg));
        }
    }
```

homeButton is always null. I checked it and found that onActivityCreated in called after this method. Any way to solve this.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        homeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_btn_home);

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: One way I think is to put 1 sec timer before calling method of fragment. But dont think its much feasible

Comment: homeButton is null for other reason. What is homeButton and how are u getting this object homeButton ? Can you show it's code ?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this method after initialization  of homeButton,,?

Comment: paste the homeButton code.

Comment: Pasted for initialization of homeButton

Comment: use homeButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_btn_home); in homeSelected() method

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [executePendingTransactions ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29) in order to execute immediately.

> After a FragmentTransaction is committed with
>   FragmentTransaction.commit(), it is scheduled to be executed
>   asynchronously on the process's main thread. If you want to
>   immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this
>   function (only from the main thread) to do so. Note that all callbacks
>   and other related behavior will be done from within this call, so be
>   careful about where this is called from. Returns
>
> ```
> Returns true if there were any pending transactions to be executed.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are calling the method `homeSelected` before the view `R.layout.fragment_home` was created.

Do this call first in activity-

```
  Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.frame_inner_container, fragment).commit();
```

Then in fragment, first call `onAttach()`,

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        //attach your activity here

}
```

Then you can call,

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

     /*Somewhere here*/
    ((HomeFragment) fragment).homeSelected(true);

}
```